# Spring + Thymleaf validation for dynamic generated fields

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I am trying to validate the input field generated dynamically. below code will give us more input:

code from HTML:

```
 <th:block th:each="word,itera : ${credentialsForm.credentialRequirements}">
          <div class="rtr_credential" style="display: inline-block;">
            <span th:text="${word.attribute}" ></span>
            <input type="hidden"  th:name="|credentialRequirements[${itera.index}].attribute|" th:value="${word.attribute}">
          </div>
          <div class="rtr_credential" style="display: inline-block;">
            <input type="text"  name="userValue" th:field="*{credentialRequirements[__${itera.index}__].userValue}" class="userValue" maxlength="30"
              th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('userValue')}? has-error : ''">  
          </div>
        </th:block>
```

It gives error as userValue is not in credentialsForm and if I include 
**th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('{credentialRequirements[__${itera.index}__].userValue}')}? has-error : ''">** 
this will throw indexing error. 
Java class structure:

```
public class CredentialRequirementForm {


    private List<CredentialRequirements> credentialRequirements;

    public List<CredentialRequirements> getCredentialRequirements() {
        return credentialRequirements;
    }
    public void setCredentialRequirements(List<CredentialRequirements> credentialRequirements) {
        this.credentialRequirements = credentialRequirements;
    }

}
```

CredentialRequirements.java

```
public class CredentialRequirements {


    private String attribute;
    private String carrierDescription;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String userValue;



    public CredentialRequirements() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CredentialRequirements(String attribute, String carrierDescription, String userValue) {
        super();
        this.attribute = attribute;
        this.carrierDescription = carrierDescription;
        this.userValue = userValue;
    }

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }
    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }
    public String getCarrierDescription() {
        return carrierDescription;
    }
    public void setCarrierDescription(String carrierDescription) {
        this.carrierDescription = carrierDescription;
    }


    public String getUserValue() {
        return userValue;
    }

    public void setUserValue(String userValue) {
        this.userValue = userValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CredentialRequirements [attribute=" + attribute + ", carrierDescription=" + carrierDescription
                + "]";
    }

}
```

How to validate the userValues, it is dynamically generated, some time only 1 attribute and some time 5 attributes. I am also trying the Jquery validate, but confuse how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answer and comments.
I need to deliver the code, so using Jquery and Javascript to validate:
Please find the code below:

```
submitHandler : function(form) {
            let invalid = 0
            $(  ".userValue" ).removeClass( "has-error" )
            $( ".userValue" ).each(function() {

              if($( this ).val() == "" ) {
                invalid++
                $( this ).addClass( "has-error" );
              }
            });
            if(invalid == 0){
                //some logic
                form.submit();
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use a `th:field` attribute to bind HTML fields to your entity fields? Then you can add a div with the error message (if there will be a validation error):

```
<th:block th:each="word,itera : ${credentialsForm.credentialRequirements}">
    <div class="rtr_credential" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span th:text="${word.attribute}" ></span>
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{credentialRequirements[__${itera.index}__].attribute}">
    </div>
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('credentialRequirements[__${itera.index}__].userValue')}"  th:errors="*{credentialRequirements[__${itera.index}__].userValue}">
        Error message
    </div>
    <div class="rtr_credential" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="text"  name="userValue" th:field="*{credentialRequirements[__${itera.index}__].userValue}" class="userValue">  
    </div>
</th:block>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried and it's not working, as per the requirement we have to highlight the column in red if any validation error is there, so appending the css class.

Comment: You can try following: `<input type="text"  name="userValue" th:field="*{credentialRequirements[__${itera.index}__].userValue}" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('credentialRequirements[__${itera.index}__].userValue')} ? 'userValueError' : 'userValue'">`

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get any errors? Or CSS class appending is not working?

Comment: The validation is not working, with blank fields, on click on save the request is going to server without any validation. Thanks I resolved it by using Jquery and javascript